# Случайный chown корня

Tags: linux, права, chown

Хотел поменять на сервере рекурсивно права в одной папке, и забыл написать точку. В итоге набрал `chown -c user:user -R /`.

Когда понял, что происходит, нажал <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, но часть файлов уже поменяло свои права.

Что можно сделать, что бы восстановить права, может быть где-то написаны эталонные права для всех стандартных папок?

Что можно сделать, чтобы в будущем не повторить этого?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Можно взять эталонную систему, например запущенную на виртуалке, набросать скрипт, который пройдется по всем папкам и сохранит владельца. Потом запустите похожий скрипт на вашей системе и восстановите права. 2) Аккуратнее работать под root. Лучше, вообще под ним не работать.

Answer (score 0):

+ еще один момент. Используйте бэкап)) Если он есть/был, то там можно посмотреть старые права. К тому же рекурсия идет от начала корня, попробуйте поискать все видоизменые права на  файлы (команда find вам в помощь) и там прикинуть а) масштабы содеяного б) что можно поменять/вернуть.

Answer (score 0):

> Что можно сделать, чтобы в будущем не повторить этого?

1. Никогда не работать под рутом.
2. Для обработки всех файлов в папке использовать:

   ```
   # только не-скрытые
   sudo chown -R user:user *

   # все файлы в этой папке, но не сама папка и не `/`
   sudo chown -R user:user * .[^.]*
   ```

   В таком случае мало шансов, что опечатка приведет вас к обработке `/`