# Ubuntu: права в /var

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

Случилась беда, я пока настраивал апач, намутил с правам в каталоге var. Все мои сайты хранятся в /var/sites.

Сейчас, у меня /var имеет chmod 755 и chown root (и все это применено к тому что есть внутри). Из-за этого, php ругается на создание сессии, т.к. сессии там хранятся (у меня var/..../../sess/), и когда скрипт php пытается удалить созданный собой же файл (он их с правами 0755 создает) - говорит permission denied, это же относится и к другим файлам, которые там были заранее. Apache, nginx и php - все работают у меня из по root.
Что мне делать в этой ситуации? (все работает если на /var/* поставить 777 - но это же беда еще большая!)

Какие права и кому куда назначить?

Благодарен за ваше внимание!

Процессы:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
    ...
root      1385  0.0  0.1 386536 26452 ?        Ss   09:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apac
www-data  1389  0.0  0.1 387548 19480 ?        S    09:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apac
www-data  1390  0.0  0.1 387536 19280 ?        S    09:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apac
www-data  1391  0.0  0.1 387432 18936 ?        S    09:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apac
www-data  1392  0.0  0.1 387408 18880 ?        S    09:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apac
www-data  1393  0.0  0.1 387184 18548 ?        S    09:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apac
```

Comment: Надо выяснить, из-под каких пользователей работает php, и обеспечить им доступ к директории. Вы очень зря химичите с /var целиком, и тем более зря дали rx для всех.

Comment: php работает из под root, я написал это. И у рута есть доступ к директории. А о том что зря - согласен, просто я первый раз настраиваю сервер на линуксе

Comment: Ага, еще вы написали, что он не может удалить рутовые файлы, а значит, это не так.

Comment: Так, каким образом вернуть все на свои места?

Comment: Понятия не имею, но выяснить, от кого он сейчас работает, придется точно.

Comment: Извеняюсь, привентил в шапку все процессы

Comment: скиньте сюда результат команды history (лучше конечно на пастбин) нак всякий, по крайней мере все оттуда что относится к настройке апача, конечно какие раньше были права не узнаем, но все же.                   drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 июн 9 15:07 var вот что у меня, правда у меня opensuse

Comment: possible duplicate of [Случайный chown корня](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/341393/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-chown-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что вам нужно для решения проблемы именно с PHP - а, скорее всего, вы прибили workflow еще не одной программе - выяснить, как он запускается. Широкоиспользуемых вариантов всего два: php-fpm и модуль апача, судя по всему, у вас второе. Это значит, что PHP действительно исполняется от пользователя www-data, и этот пользователь должен иметь доступ к соответствующей директории.

Второй аспект, неявный - это очистка хранилища сессий, которая происходит по крону. Скорее всего, она происходит от имени суперпользователя, но, тем не менее, надо в этом удостовериться, потому что все-таки нужно, чтобы механизм работал. В моем случае файл, ответственный за выполнение этой команды, лежал в `/etc/cron.d/php5`, и в нем явно написано, что команда исполняется от рута - значит, ей наплевать на права.

В идеале же вам действительно стоит тупо переставить систему. Это не очень хорошо, когда девелопер привязан к конкретной системе, и стоит уметь развертываться в течение часа-двух на абсолютно свежей машине, но, если вам будет сложно развернуть все заново, то лучше не стоит это делать. Однако индустрия предоставляет пару решений, который позволяют избавиться от таких проблем и не напортачить лишний раз - это Vagrant и Docker. Первый предоставляет простое управление виртуальной машиной, которая может переноситься с проектом просто как файл конфига, и которую из-за этого сложно убить; второй же предоставляет немного более сложный, но гораздо более быстрый функционал, который также существует в изолированной среде и сводить возомжность выстрелить в ногу своего сисадмин-эго к нулю - и Docker, и Vagrant без проблем уничтожаются и запускаются с нуля.

В целом же, индустрия сейчас очень любит immutable infrastructure - решения, в которых нерабочие/устаревшие варианты просто выкидываются, и вводятся свежие (и Docker/Vagrant очень близки к этой концепции, запорол контейнер - выкинул и поднял новый). Поэтому, конечно, стоит начать тренироваться прямо сейчас. А пока можно кинуть права 777 на весь var (это **НЕ** хорошо, но в связи с тем, что это просто рабочий ПК - можно забить), и переустановить систему при ближайшем удобном случае.

Answer (score 3):

`apache` у вас работает от имени `www-data`. вот во владение этому пользователю (и его группе) и назначьте каталог (и его содержимое), который является `docroot`-ом вашего сайта.

например, если это каталог `/var/www/html`, то выполните такие команды:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
$ sudo chmod -R u+rw,go-w /var/www/html
```

Comment: там не в docroot'е дело

Comment: @Etki, я понимаю, что натворил автор вопроса. но имеет смысл разбираться с комплексными проблемами пошагово.

Comment: Значит, я сделаю права  на /sites каталог, и сессии php перемещу например в tmp. Но, остается вопрос, какие все же права должны быть у /var ? Или, какие они по умолчанию в линуксе? И можно ли как-то вернуть эти права по умолчанию?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  16 root root   4096 июн  9 15:07 var

Comment: сам каталога /var должен принадлежать пользователю `root` и группе `root`, права: u=rwx,og=rx. **но** внутри каталога `/var` весьма разветвлённая структура файлов и каталогов, с разной принадлежностью и разными правами. причём во многих местах принадлежность и права зависят даже и не от дистрибутива или его версии, а, например, от конкретных установленных пакетов и даже от их настроек. и всё это непосредственно влияет на работоспособность и безопасность как отдельных программ, так и системы в целом. продолжение в следующем комментарии.

Comment: восстановление уничтоженных вами сущуствовавших прав — это весьма непростая проблема. если система вам не очень «дорога», то, как новичку, я бы порекомендовал вообще её переустановить.

Comment: Спасибо, можно переустановить, но попробую повозиться

Comment: Да это ПК, не сервер, я бы не торопился с переустановкой. Но вообще да, система должна быть cattle, а не pet

Comment: для восстановления прав и принадлежностей файлов-каталогов существенно мог бы помочь свежий бэкап системы (или хотя бы этого каталога), но его, как я понимаю, скорее всего, не существует.

Comment: бэкапа системы нет